# How to run Java program in command prompt

Tags: java, compilation, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I created a Java project to call a Web service.
It has one Main java file and another class file.
I have used some jar files for HTTP client.
In Eclipse it runs fine.
I need to run the Java program in command prompt by passing some arguments.
In command prompt I went to src folder containing main java and sub class java file and gave the following command

```
javac mainjava.java
```

I'm getting following error

> **mainjava.java:14: cannot find symbol
>
>   symbol  : class SubClass**

here SubClass is my another java class file used to call the web service.

How to run the program by passing arguments?

Comment: Dd you set up your class path ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`javac` is the Java compiler. `java` is the JVM and what you use to execute a Java program. You do not execute `.java` files, they are just source files.
Presumably there is `.jar` somewhere (or a directory containing `.class` files) that is the product of building it in Eclipse:

```
java/src/com/mypackage/Main.java
java/classes/com/mypackage/Main.class
java/lib/mypackage.jar
```

From directory `java` execute:

> java -cp lib/mypackage.jar Main arg1 arg2

Comment: This s my folder stucture  

webcall/src/main.java----
webcall/src/Sub.java------
webcall/extjarfiles/httpcore.jar-----
webcall/extjarfiles/httpclient.jar-----

Comment: Is there a `webcall/classes` or `webclass\lib` folder?

Comment: i used javac -cp extjarfiles/AllJarFiles main.java     ------ It compiled successfully but getting error in running the project

Comment: You need to compiler both the `Sub.java` and `main.java` and the locate the directory where the `Sub.class` and `main.class` files exist.

Comment: i compailed both java file, i got 17 warnings regarding apache ----------------------"org\apache\http\conn\scheme\SchemeRegistry.class(org\apache\http\conn\scheme:Sch
emeRegistry.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'value()' in type 'ne
t.jcip.annotations.GuardedBy': class file for net.jcip.annotations.GuardedBy not
 found
org\apache\http\impl\client\AbstractHttpClient.class(org\apache\http\impl\client
:AbstractHttpClient.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'value()' in
type 'net.jcip.annotations.GuardedBy'"

Comment: after that i run the proj by "java main hello". I got the error as "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: WSCall/ServiceCall
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WSCall.ServiceCall". Here servicecall is the main.java

Comment: From directory `webcall` try: `java -cp .:extjarfiles/httpcore.jar:extjarfiles/httpclient.jar main hello`

Answer (score 16):

A very general command prompt how to for java is

```
javac mainjava.java
java mainjava
```

You'll very often see people doing

```
javac *.java
java mainjava
```

As for the subclass problem that's probably occurring because a path is missing from your class path, the -c flag I believe is used to set that.

Comment: +1 for `javac *.java`, this will also compile the OP's SubClass.java source file.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `javac *.java` command to compile all you java sources. Also you should learn a little about classpath because it seems that you should set appropriate classpath for succesful compilation (because your IDE use some libraries for building WebService clients). Also I can recommend you to check wich command your IDE use to build your project.

Comment: In my ide using this command to run ***** "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe" -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -classpath "D:\Projects\Eclipse Projects\WebServiceCall\bin;D:\Projects\Eclipse Projects\WebServiceCall\ExternalJarFiles\httpcore-4.0.jar;D:\Projects\Eclipse Projects\WebServiceCall\ExternalJarFiles\httpclient-4.0.jar;D:\Projects\Eclipse Projects\WebServiceCall\ExternalJarFiles\commons-logging-1.1.jar;D:\Projects\Eclipse Projects\WebServiceCall\ExternalJarFiles\gson-1.7.1.jar" WSCall.ServiceCall  ****

Comment: If i use the above command in command prompt im able to run it. but i cant able to pass the arguments

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is:

- Build the mainjava class using the class path if any (optional)

  javac  *.java [ -cp "wb.jar;"]
- Create Manifest.txt file with content is:

  Main-Class: mainjava
- Package the jar file for mainjava class

  jar cfm mainjava.jar Manifest.txt *.class

Then you can run this .jar file from cmd with class path (optional) and put arguments for it.

```
java [-cp "wb.jar;"] mainjava arg0 arg1
```

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

javac only compiles the code. You need to use java command to run the code. The error is because your classpath doesn't contain the class **Subclass**  iwhen you tried to compile it. you need to add them with the -cp variable in javac command

`java -cp classpath-entries mainjava arg1 arg2`  should run your code with 2 arguments