# How to display the information about Multimedia devices in a system using command prompt?

Tags: cmd, multimedia

How can I to list the information about my multimedia devices with the command prompt?

Comment: do you want to run a java program via cmd or what?

Comment: No,actually I need cmd command to display the information about Multimedia devices in a system.

Comment: do you want us to write java code for that? Have you tried googling?

Comment: I couldn't find any. I just need the command. I can make it work in java environment.

Comment: If you can write in java in cmd you'll just have to run this program http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965818/how-to-run-java-program-in-command-prompt

Comment: I have reduced your question to its essence. Feel free to edi tif this was not what you intended to ask.

Comment: The task is to display the multimedia devices in GUI. For that, first i need to display it via command prompt @ Jan

Answer (score 0):

MSinfo32 has command line switches to create a file and may have the info you need.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300887