# Compile a .java File Programmatically

Tags: java, compilation

I want to create a program that can Compile a .java file to a .class file like it is done on this website:
[Innovation website](http://www.innovation.ch/java/java_compile.html)

My questions are:

- Is there an library i can use to do this?
- Where can I get this Library?
- If there isn't a library for this then how can i do this?

Comment: It is compiling the files. You have to get the files and pass them as arguments to the jdk. I don't think there is a library to do this. This is very straight forward once you know how java works.

Comment: @luanjot It's there in JDK since 1.6.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run Java program in command prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965818/how-to-run-java-program-in-command-prompt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the `Process` class as

```
Process pro=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac FileName.java", null, new File("\path"));
```

Comment: The /path is the output file path right?

Comment: No its input file FileName.java path, output file will be generated at the same location

Comment: O right is there an way to move the files to another directory using the process?

Comment: Nvm I just had to add -d /outputPath to the process

Comment: Ya exactly! -d <directory> to generate it to specific directory

Answer (score 6):

```
   JavaCompiler javac = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
```

The javadoc for JavaCompiler shows how to work and compile with this JDK facility. One snippet from there:

```
   File[] files1 = ... ; // input for first compilation task

   JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
   StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);

   Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits1 =
       fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(Arrays.asList(files1));
   compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, null, null, compilationUnits1).call();
```

It is by no means a simple task. But a general method for invoking a Java compiler via the shell - with all the trimmings - isn't easy either, and this, then, also applies to calls via Process.

Comment: Question: how to provide the target location of the class file to be created? 
Is there created any file in thi ssolution???

Answer (score 0):

use ProcessBuilder to execute system commands.

Install JDK and form command "javac JavaFileName" pass this to ProcessBuilder constructor and call method start()

Comment: We have seen this often enough in the referenced duplicates.