# Java: How do I run this eclipse-compiled program on the command line?

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line

I have a simple Hello World program that works properly when run from within Eclipse.  What do I need to do to run this program from the command line?

```
~/g/private/eclipse/Hello/bin --> java Hello.class
Error: Could not find or load main class Hello.class
```

Here are the eclipse-generated files:

```
~/g/private/eclipse/Hello --> find . -type f
./.classpath
./.gitignore
./.project
./.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
./bin/Hello.class
./src/Hello.java
```

and the eclipse-generated `.classpath`:

```
~/g/private/eclipse/Hello --> cat .classpath
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

(note)
I don't think this is a dupe of this question, as I'm explicitly asking about running a program compiled in eclipse.
[How to run Java program in command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965818/how-to-run-java-program-in-command-prompt)

Comment: `javac Hello.java` for compiling Hello.java source code and `java Hello` to run Hello compiled code.

Comment: It is stilll about running a java program from the command line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to give .class

```
~/g/private/eclipse/Hello/bin --> java Hello.class
```

just run like

```
~/g/private/eclipse/Hello/bin --> java Hello
```

or, specifying the class path:

```
~/g/private/eclipse/Hello java -cp bin Hello
```

Comment: Super, that works.  What if I want to run `java bin/Hello` ?

Comment: in that case tell java about your classpath and run like this : java -cp "path to bin dir" Hello

Answer (score 2):

`java.exe` or `java` **expects a class name as its argument, not a file name**

```
java -classpath C:\user\ Hello
```

So running `java Hello.class` will tell it to go looking for `hello.class.class` file.

or define classpath and use

```
java -cp C:\user\ Hello
```

PS : From Stackoverflow source