# Compiling project in Windows CMD with MySQL connector Jar

Tags: java, mysql, cmd

I have a Java project, it consists of 3 Java classes, one .properties file (including MySQL username, password etc), and a mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar

My question is how I could include the mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar when compiling. For this, I do the following right now: *Navigate to my Java project folder in CMD -> javac StartApp.java -> java StartApp.* It is running well except that it cannot find mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar when using methods that requires it.

I am using Windows 7.

What could I do? Everything else is working when running the Jar except that the connection to the MySQL is not working (since it cannot localize the connector Jar). I am getting desperate so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I am having the same problem, please answer your own question if you solve it. Or if anybody else knows.

Comment: Did you ever set the classpath ? Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965818/how-to-run-java-program-in-command-prompt

Answer (score 0):

Just add the **cp** argument to let java know the class path
lets say you are storing all your jar (mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar) under lib folder, use this command:

```
java -cp "yourMain.jar;lib/*" StartApp
```